# Condensing similar and repeating code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a fairly amateur coder but I have [searched](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=condense%20%5Bjavascript%5D%20-jquery) for the solution and didn't come up with anything.

I am working in Google sheets and what I am trying to do is add the values on the same row in two different columns together. I have tried arrays but couldn't get the first Array A to add to the first element in array B so I created the code bellow, It works OK but it seems far too wasteful (I have 21 rows to add together).

Would you be able to at least guide me to the right place to slim this down?

```js
var bd1  = data.getRange("K3");
var bn1  = data.getRange("H3").getValue();
var bo1  = data.getRange("K3").getValue();
var bs1  = bn1+bo1;
bd1.setValue(bs1); 

var bd2  = data.getRange("K4");
var bn2  = data.getRange("H4").getValue();
var bo2  = data.getRange("K4").getValue();
var bs2  = bn2+bo2;
bd2.setValue(bs2);
...
```

Comment: Have a look at common patterns. What is fixed, what is variable? For example, it seems the only variable part are the cell names, and more specifically, the index. It seems to increase from a starting value `x` (3) to some value `y`. Creating something that "counts" up is very easy to do. Have a look at `for` loops: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for . Or even if it is not a consecutive sequence, you could be an array of indexes and iterate over it.

Comment: It depends on which aspects of this are dynamic. For instance, are they always going to be K*N*, H*N*, K*N*?

Comment: FYI, "condense javascript" are not good search terms for your problem.

Comment: @Felix I had a look at that before, however I was failing at changing the cell names, I tried putting a variable into quotes.... needless to say it failed.  Rob its always going to be H and K, same problem as I mentioned to Felix

Comment: Use string concatenation, e.g. `'H' + i` produces `'H3'` if `i = 3`. Why don't you just post what you tried?

Comment: @felix neatly it was about two months ago I was working on that, I found a way around it that time (completely different method) but I think Alfredo Delgado may have answered it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you have accepted a best answer, but when making spreadsheet API calls in Google Apps Script, it is [best practice to do them in batches](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices#batchOperations) wherever possible.

You mentioned that you are doing this for 21 rows; I would therefore `getValues()` of all 21 rows first (which will return a Javascript 2D array), do the processing on that array with pure Javascript, and then `setValues()` in one go:

```
var values1 = data.getRange("H3:H23").getValues();
var range2 = data.getRange("K3:K23");
var values2 = range2.getValues();
for (var i = 0, length = values1.length; i < length; i++)
  values2[i][0] += values1[i][0];
range2.setValues(values2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to go about it:

```
var add2Cells = function(labelA, labelB) {
    var cellA  = data.getRange(labelA);
    var cellB  = data.getRange(labelB);

    cellA.setValue(cellB.getValue() + cellA.getValue());
};

add2Cells("K3", "H3");
add2Cells("K4", "H4");
```

At this point you can make an array of cell pairs that you loop through and feed into your `add2Cells` function.

Comment: That looks promising, wouldnt it be better to not have "var add2Cells = function(" but rather " function mainFunction(){ function add2cells(){} }"?

Comment: Not likely, but I'm not looking at all of your code. I added a second call to add2Cells in case that makes things any clearer.